# Ruby on Rails - Link to a URL or controller action stored in a database (in reference to Ryan B's Episode 162)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

All,

I used the railscasts.com episdoe 162 to setup a tree structure and render it as a nav pane along the top with links on the left nav as shown in the episode.  I am having a hell of a time switching from displaying the content in the database to actually redirecting to a URL or controller action as mentioned at the very bottom of this asciicast:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation

My show.html.erb action is virtually identitical to the one in the asciicast - can anyone point me in the right direction or give me a code snipped so when I click a link on the left it renderes the URL contained in my database in the main pane?  This is driving me nuts - any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam